# Не удается открыть источник файл "gmp.h"

Tags: boost, intellisense, c++

При установки boost 1.55 в Visual Studio 2010 почему-то не удается подключить

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
```

выдается ошибка

> IntelliSense: не удается открыть источник файл "gmp.h"

Хотя подключение

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp> не дает ошибки!
```

Comment: Так поставьте gmp. Это отдельный пакет, который в boost вроде входить не долже. Зависимости в MS VS никто же не отслеживает.